# Any way to include inline autocomplete in a chrome extension using omnibox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a simple chrome extension that uses an omnibox, and provides the suggested results depending on what the user enters in the address bar. I was wondering if there's anyway the suggested results could show up as inline autocompleted, instead of below the user's entry?

Thanks

Edit:

Here's a sample of what I'm doing. Basically every time the user types something in the address bar, I'm getting some suggested results and throwing them in the suggest callback, which shows those keywords stacked under the address bar. Wondering if there's anyway I could also provide the top word from this array as inline autocompleted. Sorry if the question isn't clear enough.

```
chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(function(text, suggest){
       var baseUrl = "http://sample.com";
       var finalResult = [];
              $.ajax({
                     url : baseUrl,
                     dataType : "jsonp",
                     success: function(result) {
                                     for (var i=0; i<result[1].legnth; i++){
                                          finalResult.push(
                                                 {content : result[1][i], description : result[1][i]}
                                          );
                                     }
                                     suggest(finalResult);
                              },
                     async: false
              });           
});
```

Comment: Got any more information?  Code sample?  Screenshot of what you're looking to do?  Anything?

Comment: Sure, I added some stuff as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is not currently a way, using the omnibox API, to have a suggestion populate inline instead of under the address bar as an option. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html

A look at the dev version of the documentation doesn't reveal any up coming changes to the API  either https://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/omnibox.html

Comment: there isn't even a way to change the text of omnibox !!

Comment: Can that be done using regular Javascript, fill out something on the address bar?

Comment: Yes for an input field. No for the address bar.